# Sencha EXT JS making Ext.ux.panel.PDF to work

Tags: pdf, extjs, sencha-architect

I have planned to use the Ext.ux.panel.PDF extension https://github.com/SunboX/ext_ux_pdf_panel  for my app but cannot make it to work inside my Sencha Architect 3.0. 
I have downloaded the files and put the js file in my project directory `/ext/src/ux/panel/PDF.js`. In the apllication I have put the require line on the top level under Application

```
Ext.application({

    requires: [
        'Ext.window.MessageBox',
        'Ext.ux.panel.PDF'
    ], ...
```

But when I want to instantiate the pdf panel with the code from the example I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: The following classes are not declared even if their files have been loaded: 'Ext.ux.panel.PDF'. Please check the source code of their corresponding files for possible typos: 'ext/src/ux/panel/PDF.js
```

Please advise.

**EDIT:** I have tried using a loader but the error is still present

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    paths: {
        Ext: 'ext/src'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get means, that the file `ext/src/ux/panel/PDF.js` does not contain valid javascript. I tested this extension, and I don't get that error.

It the file is empty, you will get this error only, if it contains invalid javascript, this should be the second error, while the first will complain about the syntax error. 
If the file is missing, you'll get another error.

Have a close look at the file, maybe it got corrupted while downloading or unzipping the extension. Or you edited it by error and introduced an error.

Comment: I have tried downloading the file again and replacing it but it did not do the trick. Is there only one file to include because the zip contains multiple files?

Comment: I don't know which files are required for what. Include all files. Is that error dependent on the browser ? I only tested in Chrome.

Comment: No it is the same on all browsers

Comment: Can you include your file `ext/src/ux/panel/PDF.js` ? This is really mysterious.

Comment: I deploy my files elsewhere so maybe the Architect doesn't move the files

Comment: The error clearly states that the file is there. Maybe the file is not compliant with Architect then ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43590/discussion-between-lorenz-meyer-and-jacob)

Answer (score 1):

try to add below code on top of your Ext.application({ ~~~ source

```
Ext.Loader.setPath({
    'Ext.ux' : 'YOURPATH(ABSOLUTE OR RELATIVE)/ext/src/ux'
});
```

Comment: The error clearly states that the file is there, so this cannot be the solution.